# database handling with jsni in gwt

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have a form designed in jsni, now i want that form entries to be inserted in database on button click like we do in normal java code of gwt using RPC greeting service bridge, greeting service implementation of server side and greeting service Asynchronous.
Is it possible to handle on sucess and on failure,on jsni button event.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, just read the [GWT_Jsni](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) documentation about how to use java stuff from js and viceversa. Export a java method using jsni, then when you have the form data, call that java method from js to send that data to the server, when you receive the callback, use jsni to call js.

[EDITED]

Using GQuery you could do something like this, without having to write any JSNI line nor having to deal with GWT wrappers:

```
 // Change this selector by the one which matches your elements
 GQuery.$("form input").each(new Function() {
    public void f() {
       String name = $(this).attr("name");
       String value = $(this).val();
       // Do something with name and value (RPC, databinding, etc)
    }
 });
```

NOTE: Than [GQuery](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) has nothing in common with jQuery but its API. It is enterelly written in GWT, so as you only will get compiled the code you use, and it does not load jQuery nor any external library.

Comment: i want the values entered in jsni textboxes to a java method how to do it?

Comment: I got a way for data handling that if i can get all the textboxes value in java method there i can use the Greeting service bridge for connectivity. what say?

Comment: Use [gwtquery](http://gquery.org) and you dont have to write any jsni. Just `GQuery.$("field_selector").val()`.

Comment: Try to help me with jsni I'm also trying. the document.getElementById("id").value is not working and giving a exception

Comment: sorry bt no idea about that. let me check. Thank u

Comment: Edited my response, to show how to use gQuery. IMO a GWT project without importing gwtquery makes very difficult simple things.

Comment: still not got smthng useful